# how to measure the lag of a kafka topic with consumer being a spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have a spark batch application that uses kafka as output. Is there a way to monitor Kafka consumer group lag when using spark? We checked the spark documentation and we found that spark always create a random groupId and uses a checkpoint dir to controls the offset. Is there an approach or an application that you guys recommend that we use to measure the lag of this process? We could not find a way to do it.

Comment: Where are you storing your offsets? If that location is queryable, then you can compute the difference to that and the latest offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What spark version are you using? AFAIK, you can specify `group.id`, it's not random. Also, you don't have to use checkpoint dir, you can use kafka itself for managing the offsets (refer to https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#storing-offsets)

Last but not least, I like to measure the lag from both sides - consumer metrics and broker side. The reason is that I have seen cases in which a consumer group was allegedly assigned to all partitions, but in some cases no offset was reported:

```
TOPIC     PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID
topic1     0          45896605954     46222875284     326269330  consumer-1
topic1     1          45888273257     46227424210     339150953  consumer-1
...
topic1     16         45678505506     46013061139     334555633  consumer-1
topic1     17         -               46225917726     -          consumer-1
topic1     18         45893413333     46225853655     332440322  consumer-1
```

So the consumer itself didn't report any lag on partition 17, and the only way to catch it was describing the consumer group from broker side and parse it...